# What is the purpose of Deconstruct method in KeyValuePair<> struct?

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-7.0

I was looking at `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` struct in `System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0` and this method took my attention.

Here's the signature:

```
public void Deconstruct(out TKey key, out TValue value);
```

Does it contain any logic besides simply forwarding `Key` and `Value` properties? Why would anyone ever prefer it over property getters?

Comment: It’s for the deconstruct syntax introduced in C# 7, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct. The method is not intended to be called directly, but implicitly by writing `var (key, value) = SomeMethodReturningAKeyValuePair()`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: for the 'Why prefer over property getters' part, the one that I can think of is because the property getter is a method and therefore will run every time it's accessed, potentially resulting in different values every time. But once it's deconstructed at some time point, the value at that time was preserved and can be used later, when the 'newest' property value might have already changed.

Comment: @Nico - in that case, we can still track the value in a variable manually, like `var x = object.thing`. As long as it's a value type or immutable (strings, e.g.) the value should not change. However, if you deconstruct a property that is an object, the value would be able to be updated. This is a side effect in JS, as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Deconstruction is a feature that was introduced mainly for value tuples in C# 7, letting you "unpackage all the items in a tuple in a single operation". The syntax has been generalized to allow it to be used for other types too. By defining the `Deconstruct` method, you can then use concise deconstruction syntax to assign the internal values to individual variables:

```
var kvp = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(10, "John");
var (id, name) = kvp;
```

You can even apply deconstruction to your own user-defined types by defining such a `Deconstruct` method with `out` parameters and a `void` return type, like in your example. See [Deconstructing user-defined types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct#deconstructing-user-defined-types).

**Edit**: Whilst the C# 7 deconstruction syntax is supported in both .NET Framework and .NET Core, the [`KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>.Deconstruct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.deconstruct) method is currently only supported in .NET Core 2.0 and later. Refer to the "Applies to" section in the previous link.

Answer (score 2):

Deconstuction is used to allow pattern matching (FP concepts available in Scala) in C#,This will yield key & values separatly. Also the same can use switch expression too.

```
KeyValuePairTest(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Hello", "World"));
KeyValuePairTest(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(5,7));

private static void KeyValuePairTest<TKey, TValue>(KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> keyValuePair)
{
    var (k, v) = keyValuePair;
    Console.WriteLine($"Key {k}, value is {v}");

    switch (keyValuePair)
    {
        case KeyValuePair<string, string> t:
            Console.WriteLine(t.Key + " " + t.Value);break;
        case KeyValuePair<int, int> t:
            Console.WriteLine(t.Key + t.Value); break;
    }
}
```