# Where's Deconstruct method of KeyValuePair<> struct?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, key-value, c#-7.0

I'm sure that previously I saw this method, because one year ago I've asked: [What is the purpose of Deconstruct method in KeyValuePair<> struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809890/what-is-the-purpose-of-deconstruct-method-in-keyvaluepair-struct)

But now I simply can't find it, or any trace about it's removal, any questions, nothing.

Compiler agrees:

```
var s = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 3);
var (x, y) = s;
```

> Error CS1061  'KeyValuePair' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Deconstruct' and no accessible extension method 'Deconstruct'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'KeyValuePair' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
>
> Error CS8129  No suitable 'Deconstruct' instance or extension method
>   was found for type 'KeyValuePair', with 2 out parameters and
>   a void return type.

What's going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be running your code on .NET Framework. Whilst the C# 7 deconstruction syntax is supported in both .NET Framework and .NET Core, the `Deconstruct` method for `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` is currently only supported in .NET Core 2.0 and later. You can check the "Applies to" section on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.deconstruct#applies-to).

Answer (score 6):

Oops. Looks like it was not added everywhere initially:

[As documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.deconstruct?view=netstandard-2.1):

> Applies to
>
> .NET Core
>
> - 3.0 Preview 6
> - 2.2
> - 2.1
> - 2.0
>
> .NET Standard
>
> - 2.1 Preview

Looks like I was targeting .NET Core one year ago, and now I'm on .NET Standard 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this with .net standard 2.0 (which is required when creating Source Generators). This can be easily added with:

```cs
public static class KeyValuePairExtensions {
    public static void Deconstruct<TKey,TValue>( this KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair, out TKey key, out TValue value ) {
        key   = keyValuePair.Key;
        value = keyValuePair.Value;
    }
}
```